# Estimated h/s with a specific processor

Tags: cpu-mining, cpuminer

I was just wondering how well [this processor](http://ark.intel.com/products/55626/Intel-Pentium-Processor-B940-2M-Cache-2_00-GHz) would do at bitcoin mining on cpuminer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Less than 1 USD penny per year.

Comment: I should have been more specific. What do you think the hash/s would be.

Comment: 10 Mhash/s, maybe.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I have an antminer R4 being shipped I was just curious.